# Connect App to Parse with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I wanna use Parse for my App. So I signed up and wanted to get started. I came to this Page https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/existing

The problem is, that I want to do it in Swift and I can't find an option to convert this code to Swift. Can somebody help me with that??

Tank you!

Here is my AppDelegate.swift File:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var splitViewController : UISplitViewController?




func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController!) -> Bool {

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    splitViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idSplitViewController") as? UISplitViewController
    splitViewController?.delegate = self

    splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

    let containerViewController : ContainerViewController = ContainerViewController()
    containerViewController.setEmbeddedViewController(splitViewController)

    window?.rootViewController = containerViewController


    return true
}


func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.bniedergriese.AppDelegateRepair" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("AppDelegateRepair", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("AppDelegateRepair.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Parse has yet to provide an updated version of their SDK for Swift, but here's a tutorial to get you started, including the ObjC/Swift bridging magic: http://codewithchris.com/using-parse-swift-xcode-6/

Comment: @Romain Thank you very much for this quick and helpful answer. I followed the tutorial and I am at step 4. The problem I have is, that i can't find the applicationDidFinishWithLaunching method in the AppDelegate.swift file :/

Comment: You can still add it yourself: `func applicationDidFinishLaunching(notification: NSNotification) { ... // your code }`

Comment: @invisibleUSA  look at the second function in for code posted about.  thats the didFinishWIthLaunchingOptions

Answer (score 4):

The method you mentioned is two functions down in your Swift file.

For example:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 Parse.setApplicationId("put your id number here", clientKey: "your client key here")
return true

}
```

Be sure to include

```
 #import Parse
```

at the top of your AppDelegate.swift file

Comment: Two tips: If you generate an Obj C bridging header, you will only need to import Parse once. Second, as style choice you can define API keys in a seperate file. This way you can  add them to a gitignore file.

Comment: Thanks @ericgu. I had to bypass the Obj C bridging header when first starting my project because I was getting so many errors. Hope that's not gonna be too much of an issue in future projects. :-|p Nice, still learning git but that's a good point!